# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Tags: django, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have created an API in Django, and some plain files from the desktop for angular and html. I like to fill an angular app with the API output. The request reaches the webserver, but then i get an error.

I get the following error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

So i need to add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = True or something, but where and how? I have read many issues now, tried different things where and how to add, but i cannot figure it out. Can someone please help me with this? Thanx in advance.

views.py

```
def myjson(request):
    data = Dish.objects.all()
    #data = {'string':'test', 'twee':'pollo'}
    #data = serializers.serialize('json', data)
    data = json.dumps( [{'name': o.name, 'description': o.description, 'persons': o.persons} for o in data])
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data),mimetype="application/json")
```

script.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

  $scope.dish = {};

  //$scope.dish = [{"persons": 4, "name": "Pasta Bolognese", "description": "Pasta met een saus op tomaten basis"}, {"persons": 2, "name": "Pasta Carbonara", "description": "gdsdgfgds"}, {"persons": 4, "name": "Pizzadeeg voor Big Green Egg", "description": "sdgfgfdgfd"}, {"persons": 2, "name": "Low and Slow Ribs", "description": "fdsfsdsfdfsddf"}];

  //$scope.dish = '';

  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/food/myjson/'
  })
  .success(function (data) {
    // See here, we are now assigning this username
    // to our existing model!
    $scope.dish = data;
  })
  .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

  });
}]);
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="UserCtrl">

                {{ dish }} 
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [CORS (cross-origin resource sharing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issue. It happens when you try to hit an endpoint that is on a different domain. So that'd make sense if you have a REST API for your backend.

Your API needs to set headers to allow requests from various sources. We had to allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin to allow localhost for our dev environments. I found that in Angular, with each request, you need to send `withCredentials: true` as well.

```
  $http({withCredentials: true, method: 'GET', url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/food/myjson/' })
  .success(function (data) {
      // See here, we are now assigning this username
      // to our existing model!
      $scope.dish = data;
  })
  .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

  });
```

});

Some sources say you also need to set the header on the client side as well for each request. I haven't had to do that though. But it may not hurt to include it:

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
```

Comment: You also need to enable CORS in Django. Install django-cors-headers. Full instructions on their github repo: https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers